# Bitnami Redmine 5.0.3

Tags: apache, redmine, bitnami

I need to install a bitnami redmine 5.0.3 using windows Installer. I have been assigned a VM where proxy server is configured. When installation starts but during installation it gives error for different packages that have to be installed from internet. It seems Setup is not gaining internet to install packages that is why gives error.
I tried to install on another vm without proxy setting and it installed and worked perfectly fine.
Is there any solution for installer to access internet to install packages on that proxy setting VM?

I tried to install on another vm without proxy setting and it installed and worked perfectly fine.